# Can I record browser screen without user permission?

Tags: webrtc, recording

I have requirement to record browser or tab with audio. Currently I can able to record browser and audio using chrome extension. But the problem is, I need to ask user to click on chrome extension every time.

So is there any way to record tab/browser with audio without asking user approval?

Please assist.

Comment: No, it's a huge privacy concern. I certainly wouldn't give that the heads up if I were in Chrome's QA team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Chrome values the user desire to control their own computer higher than your desire to record their actions.

See also https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-screen-share/#active-user-consent for the privacy considerations around this.

Comment: How does, for instance Smartsupp, records user screen without user aproval?

Comment: I think Smartsupp uses Smartlook, which is not recording screen but tracking browser events such as click, hover, mouse movements and so on https://www.smartlook.com/

Comment: This is also how other companies, like Hotjar do it.